# Unscented Kalman Filter Implementation for Robot Localization using wheel odometry and IMU

Tags: odometry, imu, localization, kalman-filter, encoders

I'm trying to implement an **unscented Kalman filter** algorithm for differential robot localization. The sensors I'm using are **wheel encoders** and **9-DOF IMU**. I've implemented the part of the filter for attitude estimation, and my state vector contains seven states (four are the quaternion representation of the robot, and the lateral three states are the angular velocity in three directions). Now I want to add the encoder reading to my filter to make a full pose estimation, not only an orientation estimation. I'm thinking of using the wheel encoder readings in the prediction step of the 2D pose and accelerometer readings in the update step. However, I've have read multiple articles about the cumulative error of integrating the acceleration into a 2D pose. Would the Kalman Filter eliminate this cumulative error as I'm using 2 sensors for the 2D pose esitmation?